# type mismatch: expected associated type found struct

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types

I have the following example code:

```
trait Manager: Sized {
    type Item: Item<Manager=Self>;
}

trait Item: Sized {
    type Manager: Manager<Item=Self> = DefaultManager<Self>;
}

struct DefaultManager<T: Item<Manager=DefaultManager<T>>>(::std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: Item<Manager=DefaultManager<T>>> Manager for DefaultManager<T> {
    type Item = T;
}
```

Which produces the warning (and future error):

```
<anon>:9:5: 9:61 warning: type mismatch resolving `<Self as Item>::Manager == DefaultManager<Self>`: expected associated type, found struct `DefaultManager` [E0271]
<anon>:9     type Manager: Manager<Item=Self> = DefaultManager<Self>;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:9:5: 9:61 help: see the detailed explanation for E0271
<anon>:9:5: 9:61 note: this warning results from recent bug fixes and clarifications; it will become a HARD ERROR in the next release. See RFC 1214 for details.
<anon>:9     type Manager: Manager<Item=Self> = DefaultManager<Self>;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:9:5: 9:61 note: required by `DefaultManager`
```

My question is where is the type mismatch coming from? The warning highlights the default value for `Item::Manager` but notes that the type requirement being broken comes from `DefaultManager`. If I remove the default value for `Item::Manager` the warning goes away however I'd prefer to keep the default value. Changing

```
struct DefaultManager<T: Item<Manager=DefaultManager<T>>>(...)
```

to

```
struct DefaultMananger<T: Item>
```

(but leaving the associated type constraint on the `Manager` impl for `DefaultManager`) also clears the warning but is possibly less-than-ideal because it would allow something like the following to happen:

```
struct Foo;
impl Item for Foo { type Manager = FooManager; }

struct FooManager;
impl Manager for FooManager { type Item = Foo; }

type DefaultFooManager = DefaultManager<Foo>;
```

In that case `DefaultManager<Foo>` should not be a valid type because `<Foo as Item>::Manager` is `FooManager`, not `DefaultManager<Foo>`.

What is causing the type mismatch and how can I clarify to the compiler that the type constraints are met?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm using the unstable `associated_type_defaults` feature so that I can provide a default value for `Item::Manager` so this example only builds on nightly at the moment.

Comment: @Shepmaster Good point, I added a clarification.